# SQL Delete using select on linked server issue

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have 2 databases with the same tables. 
Both databases are on different SQL servers.
I added the second SQL server as a linked server, which works fine.

I want to run a simple DELETE on the linked DB (so that ID's that aren't on the local DB will be deleted).

When I have both DB's on the same server, it works

```
DELETE FROM TM.dbo.Departments
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SPO.dbo.Departments 
WHERE TM.dbo.Departments.DepartmentID = spo.dbo.Departments.DepartmentID);
```

But when I try this on the Linked Server, it looks like this

```
DELETE FROM [LINKEDSRV].[TM].[dbo].[Departments]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SPO.dbo.Departments WHERE 
spo.dbo.Departments.DepartmentID = [LINKEDSRV].[TM].[dbo].[Departments].DepartmentID)
```

And the last line with is where I can't get it to work.
I hope you guys have a suggestion!

Comment: What error messages are you getting.

Comment: Use of 3+ naming convention to reference columns is deprecated, and should be avoided. It will stop working in a future version of SQL Server.

Comment: The multipart identifier could not be bound. SQL management studios underlines the last part _[LINKEDSRV].[TM].[dbo].[Departments].DepartmentID)_ and I get it, because it isn't a 4 part identifier, but a 5 part, which isn't allowed..., But I have no idea how I should write this in correct TSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE LS
FROM [LINKEDSRV].[TM].[dbo].[Departments] LS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SPO.dbo.Departments D
                  WHERE D.DepartmentID = LS.DepartmentID)
```

As I mentioned in the comments, 3+ naming for columns is deprecated (i.e. `schema.object.column`). Alias your objects and then prefix the column name with that for succinct and readable SQL.